# Can't populate a recycler using a collection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I want each row of my RecyclerView to display all the details of one document of the collection.

I've used this exact same adapter code, albeit with a different class to serialize into. And it works well. But in this instance, it's simply not working.
But the code just doesn't get into populating the views.

My database is like:

```
reviews--Orange--vault--|
                        |-firstReview
                        |-secondReview
                        |-sjdeifhaih5aseoi
                         ...
```

My query and adapter from the fragment:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ReviewViewModel::class.java)

        val reviewQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("reviews").document("Orange").collection("vault")
        val reviewBurnOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Review>()
            .setQuery(reviewQuery, object : SnapshotParser<Review> {
                override fun parseSnapshot(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot): Review {
                    return snapshot.toObject(Review::class.java)!!.also {
                        it.id = snapshot.id
                    }
                }
            }).setLifecycleOwner(this)

        reviewRecycler.adapter=ReviewBurnAdapter(reviewBurnOptions.build())}

    class ReviewBurnAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Review>) :
        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Review, ReviewBurnAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {//I never reach this point
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_review, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, item: Review) {
            holder.apply {
                holder.itemView.rowAuthor.text = item.author
            }
        }


        inner class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer
    }
```

Class to serialize into:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
import com.google.firebase.firestore.PropertyName
import java.util.*

class Review(
    @get:Exclude var id: String = "DEVIL",

    @JvmField @PropertyName(AUTHOR) var author: String = "",
    @JvmField @PropertyName(WRITEUP) var writeup: String = "",
    //@JvmField @PropertyName(MOMENT) var moment:Date=Date(1997,12,1),
    @JvmField @PropertyName(RATING) var rating: Int = 0
) {
    companion object {
        const val AUTHOR = "author"
        const val WRITEUP = "writeup"
        const val RATING = "rating"
        //const val MOMENT="moment"
    }
}
```

Also, there's no errors, it just never reaches the code that would generate and populate with viewHolders.

Comment: I think you missed one important method of `Adapter` ie `getItemCount()`

Comment: In addition to @iCantC comment, also check if you have set `layoutManager ` for `RecyclerView` or not. Before that make sure you are getting the data from `FirebaseFirestore`. If it doesn't work well try posting the complete Activity code.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Please also add the content of your `Review` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the fix was ultra simple, as @Prashant Jha pointed out, I hadn't specified a layout manager for my RecyclerView -_-

To be crystal clear, I added             app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

to my xml, and everything worked.